# Occasional delay when creating a WCF service channel

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a windows service that uses WCF (with config in code) that uses an API that also uses WCF (with its own config in code). I am getting occasional delays in the api when the channels are being created - these last anywhere between a few seconds to several minutes (and longer according to external reports).

When using the API in a test application (a simple Windows Forms test app) I can call the method that is being affected thousands of times in a loop without issue.

I have used the service tracer to determine the cause but it is not really pointing me in any specific direction. I include a screenshot of the trace below.  As can be seen there is a delay creating the service channel. After the delay the call is always successful.

If I am interpreting correctly the stage 'Identity was determined for an endpoint reference' is taking over three minutes to complete in this case.

Does anybody have any suggestions as to what is causing this delay and how to fix it or any suggestions on further diagnostics?

SvcLog:

[image: SvcLog]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: Do you have identity elements inside your endpoints on the client and the service...and if so, are they userPrincipalName or servicePrincipalName? These are authenticated in the service and can take some time. I have found them to be a source of startup delays...but never anything like 3 mins.

Comment: Are you in a domain? The AD may be taking too long to authenticate the request. It has nothing to do with your client or service. Search for `Identity was determined for an EndpointReference` in [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saurabs/2014/01/13/wcf-discover-identity-in-wcf-world/). Even if not domain, it is the authentication which is taking long. in either case this happens during the handshake.

Comment: Since you've got dual-channel services, I assume they're self-hosted, in which case the identity is easy to mess up...especially if the service is moved. Here's yet one more [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/overriding-the-identity-of-a-service-for-authentication) to look at. (just saw the .aspx extension...so this probably isn't the issue)